# Spring Data Mongo DB Criteria - Difference between dates

Tags: mongodb, spring-mongodb

I am using spring framework mongoDB Criteria. I have an object A with startDateTime and endDateTime saved in MongoDB. I want to write a query where startDateTime + minutes is less than endDateTime.

```
Criteria.where("endDateTime").gte("startDateTime") plus minutes)
```

Please help me in writing the query.